# Why is "Content Downloaded" in the network tab over a minute long for Firestore query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, performance, google-cloud-firestore

When I query my Firestore database, it seems to execute quickly - I get the data back and I render what I need to on the screen. But, when I look at the request in the network tab of the Chrome dev tools, the Content Downloaded section (the blue bar) shows that it takes over minute to download. Why is this happening? The data is fetched and rendered much quicker than that, and also, the size of the data being returned is not that large (12.7kB transferred over the network). Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot of network tab]

Is this something I should be concerned about? I'm really just looking for clarity/understanding on this issue, because currently I'm confused why the query seems to be so fast in terms of what I see on the screen, vs why the content download takes such a long time.

Also for context, this is taking place in a React app made with create-react-app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Firestore JavaScript SDK uses web channel as its protocol for talking to the server. This means that it opens a long-lasting HTTP connection over which the server can inform the client of updates to the data, a process known as long polling.

What you're seeing in the network tab is this long polling: a connection that stays open and receives data for a relatively long time, but that doesn't cause any performance problems in your ap. This is a normal part of Firestore's wire protocol and not something to be worried about.

If you'd like to learn more about Firestore's communication between client and server, I'd recommend [enabling its debug logging](https://gist.github.com/katowulf/0475fb7a5907ed757f687aab6ed15878#file-enable_debug_logging-js) and inspecting the output, as it generally is much more readable than than the raw wire traffic.